# Ruby 2: Detect encoding from binary ASCII-8BIT data

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii-8bit

I have to load some data from external sources. When I look at the encoding, Ruby tells me `ASCII-8BIT`, binary file. However, some of the sources are encoded `ISO-8859-1` and some of them are in `UTF-8`. When I try to convert the `ISO-8859-1` encoded stuff to `UTF-8`, I get an error. But when I do something like `content.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')` everything works fine.

However, this doesn't work the other way round. When I try to encode the UTF-8 data to ISO, it ends up with broken characters like `ï»¿`.

> So, is there a way to detect the "underlying" encoding of the
>   `ASCII-8BIT` data, and then convert it to `UTF-8`?

Comment: A quick search found a library which might solve your problem... https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes

Comment: This is just not possible in a reliable way. Only heuristic approaches exist.

Comment: @AJFaraday I tried that gem, works like a charm! If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: There's no absolutely reliable way to do this, you really need to keep track of what files are in what encoding. But if you have to guess, there are some gems that will help you guess, but it will not be absolutely reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick google and found the Charlock Holmes gem by Brian Lopez. It looks like it does the detection process you're after.

https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes